# Divide a value by it's group max value in sql

Tags: sql

I have some data which looks like :

| Class | Time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 1 | 14 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 56 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 32 |
| ... | ... |

How to write a SQL query to find a average of a class score?

Class score : (100 * Time) / max(Time of that class) [kind of a % but instead of total time of that class we will use max time of that class.]

Expected result is :

`for 1 : avg( (12 * 100 / max(12, 14, 56)), (14 * 100 / max(12, 14, 56)), (56 * 100 / max(12, 14, 56)))`

same for all values

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use subquery or window function for to get maximal value per group.

Comment: Have you have had a look at `AVG`?

Comment: @Larnu yes, AVG is necessary.

Comment: What are the expected results?

Comment: `MAX(Time) OVER (PARTITION BY Class)`. And no, what you've got there is not an average.

Comment: A basic algebraic manipulation will help simplify things.  `AVG( a*100/x , b*100/x, c*100/x ) == AVG(a, b, c) * 100 / x`

Comment: In fact this is kind of normalization on numbers. am I true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table and data

```
create table classes(Class int,Time int);
```

```
insert into classes values(1,12),(1,14),(2,3),(1,56),(3,4),(5,32);
```

```
select Class,(100*Time)/max(Time) over(PARTITION BY Class) from classes;
```

results ....

```
 class | ?column?
-------+----------
     1 |       21
     1 |       25
     1 |      100
     2 |      100
     3 |      100
     5 |      100
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely in your math formula, you will notice that it can be simplified a lot.
So this simple query will give same result

```
SELECT class, SUM(time*100)/(MAX(time)*COUNT(*))
FROM *table_name*
GROUP BY class;
```

Comment: Or, even more simply; `AVG(time) * 100 / MAX(time)` *(which also has specific behaviour for handling NULLs)*

Comment: But some classes can have same max values. I think in that case it will give wrong values.

Answer (score 0):

Using subquery like this `SELECT MAX(time) FROM test1 as b WHERE a.class = b.class` help you to find max value of each class group.
In this example I suppose table `test1` as your table whitch contains `time` and `class` columns. `test1` used two times in this query with `a` and `b` alias. `special_avg` column is your calculated value:

```
SELECT *, 
    (100 * time / (SELECT MAX(time) FROM test1 as b WHERE a.class = b.class)) as special_avg    
FROM test1
```